# How can I extract string 'foo' from a string foo@mail.com?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
select left(emailaddress, len(emailaddress) - charindex('@', emailaddress))
```

I am getting the result below:

```
foo@ma
```

Please correct the select statement below.  I need to do this with tones of email addresses and extract the username ONLY.

Comment: Removed your actual email, just in case, feel free to add it back if I am mistaken; no point sharing your email address (if it was) for spammers to get :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're inadvertently re-implementing "right" there :)

Try this:

```
select left(emailaddress, charindex('@', emailaddress) - 1)
```

It seeks the position of the `@`, and takes the number of characters up to but not including (that's the `- 1`) the `@` symbol.

Be careful with strings that don't have an `@` though; you'll end up an empty string.

Comment: I don't know, why -1? charindex gives an index, and left takes a length as far as I understood that?

Comment: Ayup. Charindex counts from the left, so if you want the left part of the string, just subtract 1 so you don't include the search character (@) itself. You'd only need the length of the string if you wanted the *right* part of the string, i.e. *after* the search character.

Comment: example: a@b.com
charindex returns 1
left( a@b.com, 1) returns a -> what we want. so we don't need the minus 1.

Comment: @StampeedXV, for a@b.com, charindex returns 2, not 1.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks a bunch - very helpful specially the strings that do not have an '@' - thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Damn. Made an error in my test :(. Although returning 2 is not what I expected in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it with tons (or tonnes but certainly *not* tones) of email addresses and/or you're doing it frequently, the right time to do it is when the data enters the table (by using an insert/update trigger) and splitting it into two columns at that point. That way, it only happens when needed, not every time you do a select on the table.

Data is almost *always* read far more often than written so, by splitting at insertion/update time, you minimize the amount of work to be done. Per-row functions never scale well as your tables get bigger and it's a much smaller cost to simply concatenate two columns than to split them based on a character separator.

The other answers already tell you how to do the split. It's my contention that you're doing it at the wrong time. Of course, if a schema change is out of the question, just ignore this response. But, in my opinion, that would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
select left(emailaddress, charindex('@', emailaddress)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. I don't have any access to sql-server, not a familiarity with it. But...

Have you tried:

```
 select left(emailaddress, charindex('@', emailaddress))
```

Comment: This would include the @ character. You need to subtract 1 to get all the characters up to but not including the search character.

Comment: Actually, that depends if strings are zero-indexed or 1-indexed. If zero-indexed, charindex returns 3, thus you get the 3 left characters. A 1-based string would return 4, thus it would include the '@'.

Comment: But in TransactSQL, charindex is 1-based! See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was just guessing based on the output given by OP.

Comment: Heh. Now the question got changed (e-mail change). Let's assume the editor provided the correct output for the original query (the one with len - charindex).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works in a situation where you know what the domain part of the email address is going to be, but you want to extract the first part, which will be the username. For example, I work for a college where email addresses are firstname.lastname@college.edu, and firstname.lastname is used as the login username. Sometimes I need a list of just usernames, but those are not stored in our database separately from the entire email address. So, I use this:

```
REPLACE(email_address,'@college.edu','')
```